# Validate and Compare between two dictionaries when both Dictionaries value contains List like "Dictionary<string, List<string>>"

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hi two generic dictionaries as below syntax format

`Dictionary<string, List<string>> Test1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); Dictionary<string, List<string>> Test2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

now i need to compare and validate this two dictionaries

sample data will be like

**Example 1**

**Test1**

| String | List |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple, Banana |
| B | Grape, Pears |
| C | Orange, cherry |

**Test2**

| String | List |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple, Banana, Watermelon |
| B | Grape, Pears |
| C | Orange, cherry |

this above example should be validated and find that test1 is not contain in Test2

**Example 2**

**Test3**

| String | List |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple, Banana |
| B | Grape, Pears |
| C | Orange, cherry |

**Test4**

| String | List |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple, Banana |
| B | Grape, Pears |
| C | Orange, cherry |
| D | Mango, Pineapple, plum |

this above example should be validated and find that test3 is contains in Test4

Comment: you should definilty think abut making your dictionaries classes. That way you get really usefull propeties that have names and static types. Furthermore it's fairly easy to implement equality for classes

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. What have you tried so far? Where do you stuck? For me it looks like a linq-one-liner.

Comment: How about you explain what the actual rules are? Examples are good but if you provide only examples then there are countless ways to get the specific results you describe. If you're going to write general code to handle every case then you have to know what the specific rules are for every case. It's obvious that most people would not consider your Test3 to "contain" Test4 so you you need to actually explain what "contains" means in this context. Maybe if you put some thought into the rules then you'll able able to at least start writing the code yourself.

Comment: Also, the title says that you need to find the difference while the questions talks about find whether one list contains the other. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. Provide ALL the relevant details and don't contradict yourself. If you'd like us to volunteer our time to help, don't make us waste that time asking you to explain what you should have already explained.

Comment: @user18387401 its my bad, i will update the title as Validate and Compare, i looking for the scenario, when Test1 is dic is completely exists in Test2 (i,e Test1 should be available in Test2 no changes in list).

Comment: So you want to know whether or not the second dictionary contains all the keys from the first and that all those keys have the same values, correct?

Comment: @user18387401 yes, that's correct. even list values should be same. if any difference application has to notify.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if order of strings within `List<>` is unimportant then consider using `HashSet<>` instead of `List<>`.  Code below does what I think you intend...

```
static bool List1IsSubsetOfList2(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  return !list1.Except(list2).Any();
}

static bool List1ContentsSameAsList2(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
  // if order is relevant do not sort
  list1.Sort();
  list2.Sort();
  // same entry values in same order
  return list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
}

static bool Dictionary1SubsetDictionary2(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict1, Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict2)
{
  var k1 = dict1.Keys.ToList();
  var k2 = dict2.Keys.ToList();
  var fKeys = List1IsSubsetOfList2(k1, k2);
  return fKeys && k1.All(k => List1ContentsSameAsList2(dict1[k], dict2[k]));
}

var test1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
   { "A", new List<string> { "Apple", "Banana" } }
  ,{ "B", new List<string> { "Grape", "Pears" } }
  ,{ "C", new List<string> { "Orange", "Cherry" } }
};
var test2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
   { "A", new List<string> { "Apple", "Banana", "Watermelon" } }
  ,{ "B", new List<string> { "Grape", "Pears" } }
  ,{ "C", new List<string> { "Orange", "Cherry" } }
};
var test3 = test1;
var test4 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
   { "A", new List<string> { "Apple", "Banana" } }
  ,{ "B", new List<string> { "Grape", "Pears" } }
  ,{ "C", new List<string> { "Orange", "Cherry" } }
  ,{ "D", new List<string> { "Mango", "Pineapple", "Plum" } }
};

Console.WriteLine($"Test1 is contained in Test2 {Dictionary1SubsetDictionary2(test1,test2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Test2 is contained in Test1 {Dictionary1SubsetDictionary2(test2,test1)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Test3 is contained in Test4 {Dictionary1SubsetDictionary2(test3,test4)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Test4 is contained in Test3 {Dictionary1SubsetDictionary2(test4,test3)}");
```

with result

```
Test1 is contained in Test2 False
Test2 is contained in Test1 False
Test3 is contained in Test4 True
Test4 is contained in Test3 False
```